# Is there a "createObject" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jscript

In VBScript there is a function called CreateObject, which can be run on a client through a webpage.  I've used it before like this:

```
Set icaObj = CreateObject("Citrix.ICAClient")
CitrixVersion = icaObj.ClientVersion
```

To find out which version of the application was installed on the client machine.

Is there something comparable in JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232242/how-to-work-with-com-object-using-javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there something comparable in JavaScript?

Not in **JavaScript**, but in Microsoft's JScript in limited environments, yes:

```
var icaObj = new ActiveXObject("Citrix.ICAClient");
```

And just like VBScript, this will only work in a very limited situation: Specificially, something running with Internet Explorer with full permissions (or, of course, in JScript running on the server).