# How to invoke uft script present in ALM using java script?

Tags: javascript, hp-uft, alm

My requirement is to execute the UFT scripts based on the input given in html page. I came to know from  some of the blogs that Microsoft has stopped vbs script usage in html. for that reason  i want to invoke the qtp scripts using java script. I searched for the same and didnt find much information. If anyone can provide the equivalent code in javascript will be helpful. I am in short of time to experiment as the client demo is near.

```
Dim objQtpApp
Set objQtpApp=Createobject("QuickTest.Application")
objQtpApp.Launch
objQtpApp.Visible=False 'True
varUserName=document.getElementsByName('Username').value
varPassword=document.getElementsByName('Password').value



call QC_Connect(varUserName,varPassword)

Sub QC_Connect(varUserName,varPassword,varCustomsON)

'   
    objQtpApp.TDConnection.Connect "http://dddd.fed.test.com:7117/qcbin", "Domain", "Project", varUserName, varPassword,False

    If objQtpApp.TDConnection.IsConnected Then

            objQtpApp.Open "[QualityCenter] Subject\Automated Test Case Development\Test",False  
            objQtpApp.Test.Environment.Value("varUserName")=varUserName
            objQtpApp.Test.Environment.Value("varPassword")=varPassword
            objQtpApp.Test.Environment.Value("varCustomsON")=varCustomsON
            objQtpApp.Test.Run
            objQtpApp.Quit


    Else
        MsgBox "Cannot connect to Quality Center"
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem will be that [JavaScript doesn't have an equivalent of `CreateObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414323/is-there-a-createobject-in-javascript).

The only browser that supports Microsoft's alternative (`new ActiveXObject("...")`) is IE (not Edge) and it also supports VBScript so there's no point in porting your code to JavaScript.