# Issues in using Excel.Application COMObject with Javascript and Spidermonkey (within Sparx EA)

Tags: javascript, enterprise-architect, spidermonkey

I'm using Sparx Enterprise Architect to create a script that needs to generate an Excel file.
Until now I've used VBScript and JScript, but I need for a new project to implement it with Javascript.
Sparx EA uses Mozilla SpiderMonkey JS v1.8.

I started with the following code:

```
function main()
{
    try {
    var objExcel= new COMObject("Excel.Application",true);      
    var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(true);
    var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets.Add("",1);
    }   
    catch (ex)
    {
        Session.Output("exception " + ex);
    }   
}
main();
```

Unfortunately this generates the following error:
**exception TypeError: objWorkbook is undefined**

Comment: Calling COM objects with JavaScript is a bad idea...

Comment: I got no idea about any JavaX stuff. But maybe this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232242/how-to-work-with-com-object-using-javascript ?

Comment: Using scripts in Sparx EA is required as users can execute them without having to individually install an addin. Javascript is recommended by SparxSystems and it has the advantage of supporting classes (contrary to Ms JScript and VBScript). I managed to use Javascript to implement a Logging class matching the built-in JScript-Logging. I'm hoping to find a way to get the Excel Application work..

Answer (score -1):

From MS documentation Workbook:

`public object Add (object Before, object After, object Count, object Type);`

All parameters are optional, if no parameter is passed it returns a Worksheet

[You can see online documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.add?view=excel-pia)